# QImage: out of memory, returning null image

Tags: qt, qimage

```
   QImage img(data_image, Nc, Nl, Nc, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
            // Создание таблицы цветов.
            QVector<QRgb> color_table;
            for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
            {
                color_table.append(qRgb(i,i,i));
            }
            img.setColorTable(color_table);
            QImage optimal_img = img.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_Mono);
            delete data_image;
            p.drawText(font_X,font_Y,setable_text);
            QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
            scene->setSceneRect(0,0,28400,28400);
            QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(optimal_img));
            QGraphicsPixmapItem *item1 = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(optimal_img));
            QGraphicsPixmapItem *item2 = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(optimal_img));
            QGraphicsPixmapItem *item3 = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(optimal_img));
            QGraphicsPixmapItem *item4 = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(optimal_img));
 // на этот и следующий не хватает памяти            
            QGraphicsPixmapItem *item5 = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(optimal_img));
            QGraphicsPixmapItem *item6 = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(optimal_img));
            scene->addItem(item);
            scene->addItem(item1);
            scene->addItem(item2);
            scene->addItem(item3);
            scene->addItem(item4);
            scene->addItem(item5);
            //scene->addItem(item6);
            item1->setPos(7100, 0);
            item2->setPos(0, 7100);
            item3->setPos(7100, 7100);
            item4->setPos(14200, 7100);
            item5->setPos(14200, 14200); 
            item6->setPos(14200, 28400);
            ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

Создаю сцену и помещаю на нее изображения размером `7100х7100` формата `QImage::Format_Mono`. При попытке создать  больше 5 объектов типа `QGraphicsPixmapItem` изображений выдается предупреждение о том, что кончилась оперативная память: `QImage: out of memory, returning null image`. Она действительно закончилась, но я не очень понимаю, почему объекты `QGraphicsPixmapItem` занимают так много места, ведь:

```
QImage::Format_Mono
The image is stored using 1-bit per pixel.
```

Или я что-то неверно понимаю? И как в таком случае мне разместить хотя бы 20-24 изображения на сцене?
Пример изображения:

[image: Пример изображения]

Comment: А можете привести кусок изображения в вопросе? Просто уж очень дикое берёте разрешение для бинарной картинки. Может это у Вас текстура, и нужно просто брать маленький кусочек, и уже его штамповать кистью.

Comment: @alexis031182 Добавил изображение, если приглядеться, то там есть белые пиксели. Это изображение, имитирующее кадр звездного неба, сформированный с фотоматрицы.

Comment: А ну тогда Вам не нужно создавать растровое изображение. У Вас получается, что полезной информации минимум на по сути огромной площади фона. Вам нужно работать с векторным изображением. Хранить в памяти только координаты точек (звёзд).

Comment: банальная математика говорит, что Вам нужно почти гиг памяти. (один пиксель - 4 байта, одна картинка - 7100*7100 * 4 = около 192МБайт). Если ось 32битная, то вполне возможно, что память кончилась. Вам реально нужны такие большие картинки? Ваш монитор вряд ли шире 1920 пикселей.

Comment: @KoVadim Эти картинки затем будут отправляться на печать в типографию. Они не для просмотра на мониторе.

Comment: @bronstein87, типография, по идее, может принять векторный svg (в Qt он есть).

Comment: @alexis031182, а как из массива данных в qt сформировать векторное изображение? или тут нужно идти другим путем, не подскажете?

Comment: тогда ответ прост  - либо грузите по одной картике, либо в памяти держите только в векторном виде (грубо говоря - список точек и их радиус. А потом, когда нужно отдать в печать - уже отрисовывайте реальные картинки. Хотя я бы в печать отдавал в ps формате. В Вашем случае они будут сильно меньше и многие типографии получат больше свободы (ps - это такой формат, который нативно понимают принтеры и плоттеры и если картинку нужно будет распечатать на 100х100 метров, то звезды будут все равно круглые)

Comment: @bronstein87, ну вот собственно KoVadim опередил. Единственное, ps в Qt не поддерживается, вроде. Как в него экспортировать графику со сцены, лично я не знаю.

Comment: ps не такой сложный формат, и сабжевая картинка довольно простая, можно сформировать файл ps самостоятельно

Comment: @BeardedBeaver, напишите, пожалуйста, ответ с примером конвертации в ps. Лично мне тоже будет интересно. Я просто когда носил свои векторные картинки в типографию, то экспортировал в svg, а там у них имелся CorelDraw, который svg без проблем берёт.

Comment: @alexis031182 извините, но я всё-таки не очень понял. в моей программе формируется массив, из которого я потом делаю растровое изображение с помощью QImage. а как мне действовать, чтобы сформировать векторное изображение?

Comment: @bronstein87 я не очень понял, боевое изображение будет сплошным черным фоном с белыми точками, или фон будет неоднородного цвета (реальное небо) с градиентами и переливами, а звезды разного размера? Во втором случае векторный вариант не подойдет.

Comment: @bronstein87 Вам нужно будет с массива сразу генерировать svg. [svg](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) - это текстовый формат, обычный xml. Даже описания на википедии должно хватить.

Comment: @ Bearded Beaver, будет большой черный квадрат с маленькими белыми квадратами одинакового размера в нем :)

Comment: @alexis031182, ради интереса попробовал на двух других машинах и получил странные результаты. изначально на 3 гб оперативной памяти (win7 32) формировалось 5 изображений, на остальные 2 не хватало памяти ( и действительно там оставалось 50 мб), теперь попробовал на win7 64 сначала 4 гб, там почему-то получилось создать всего 4 объекта, затем на win7 64 8 гб вообще всего 3, хотя показывает, что свободной оперативной памяти в первом и втором случае ещё предостаточно. как так может быть?

Comment: @bronstein87, точного ответа не знаю, но вот когда Вы переводите изображение из `QImage` в `QPixmap`, формат также конвертируется. То есть рисуется отнюдь не `Mono` и там скорее всего какой-нибудь, по типу RGB32 с альфа-каналом или ещё чего похлеще. `QPixmap` ориентирован для быстрого рисования, а отнюдь не для экономии. Что там за расходы получаются на конкретном железе, мне сказать сложно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По просьбам трудящихся небольшой туториал по использованию postscript для рисования векторной графики. Файл ps представляет собой просто текстовый файл с описанием разметки страницы. Файл состоит из последовательных команд, параметры команды пишутся перед командой и кладутся в стек при разборе файла устройством. Примеры команд:

**x y moveto** переносит курсор в указанную точку

**x y lineto** рисует линию из точки, где стоит курсор в указанную

**x y rmoveto/rlineto** то же самое, только указывается смещение относительно текущего положения

после окончания описания контура необходим вызов команды **stroke**, непосредственно выполняющей рисование

**x y w h rectstroke** рисует прямоугольник из точки x y шириной w и высотой h

Координатная система оперирует пунктами, 0,0 в нижнем левом углу, дефолтно один пункт равен 1/72 дюйма.

Код, сохранения примитивного ps файла:

```
QFile file(QApplication::applicationDirPath()+"/out.ps");
QTextStream stream(&file);
file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
stream << "%!PS-Adobe-2.0" << "\n";   //заголовочная строка, по ней корел определит, что это за файл. 
//Без нее файл является корректным с точки зрения синтаксиса, но в корел не импортируется :) 
stream << "20 20 500 500 rectstroke\n"; //рисуем прямоугольник
stream << "newpath" << "\r\n";  //начинаем новую полилинию

stream << "30 30 moveto " << "\r\n";
stream << "30 60 lineto " << "\r\n";
stream << "60 60 lineto " << "\r\n";
stream << "60 90 lineto " << "\r\n";    //описываем полилинию

stream << "stroke" << "\r\n";  //непосредственно рисуем

file.close();
```

При импорте файла в CorelDraw видим следующее:
[image: При импорте файла в CorelDraw видим следующее]

Я привел базовые принципы и команды, возможности языка (фактически postscript является языком разметки страниц) намного шире, в интернетах есть множество справочников по языку, дальше разобраться не составит труда.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `QPixmap QPixmap::fromImage(QImage &&image, Qt::ImageConversionFlags flags = Qt::AutoColor)` (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ImageConversionFlag-enum) позволяет установить параметр `Qt::NoFormatConversion`, который запрещает конвертацию исходного формата `QImage` в формат `RGB32` с включенным альфа каналом. Данный способ подходит если необходимо разместить как можно больше изображений на сцене в ущерб тому, что скролинг и масштабирование их на `QGraphicView` становится сверх медленным и тормознутым. ( для меня этот предпросмотр на `QGraphicView` как дополнительная фича и посему этот минус не является столь критичным).

Comment: Вы может быть поторопились. @BeardedBeaver вроде не отказался написать пример для вектора. С вектором - правильное решение в Вашей ситуации.

Comment: @alexis031182, если напишет, будет замечательно, а так хоть какой-то выход :)